# Question on C# threading with RFID

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, rfid

My question is for feedback on making sure I am taking the right approach, and handling the threading correctly. I have a feeling I may need to set of some of my own threads, so all feedback is welcome.

The problem I have is reading RFID tags from zero or more RFID readers. I can read for a single reader without an issue so reading from several will not be an issue. Each Tag or batch of Tags read by the reader is delivered by a .Net Event.

My plan is to setup a ReaderControl class, which maintains the readers, connection, starting, stopping, etc. This class will listen to the **TagRead** events from the readers. On each event it handles (roughly every 250ms) it puts the read tag ids (a string) into a HashSet to keep them unique, the HashSet is located in ReaderControl. The ReaderControl will contain a timer, that fires/elapses every 500ms, this TimerElapsed event is handled by the ReaderControl which will package up the tags read from all readers so far and raise a **TagsRead** event. The purpose of this is to keep event firing to a minimum and reduce duplicate tags.

The **TagsReads** event is handled by another class called TagTranslator. This class will loop through the tag ids (strings) and work out what the tag refers to, i.e. IPerson object. This class will fire an event on completion of the translation with a **PeopleSeen** event.

The **PeopleSeen** event is handled by a model in a GUI (MVP pattern). The overall idea is a GUI display is shows names of people which pass through the RFID readers. The display is simply but obviously under the hoods tags are being read in asych and been translated to "real" objects to be displayed.

Do you feel ReaderControl should be running on its own thread, I think it should. How do I go about packaging this class in its own thread to just keep reading tags regardless of what the GUI is doing. Also, do you think when the TagTranslator when handling events should create threads to handle the translation.

Comment: sounds like the most complicated CPU intensive way of handling  RFIDs i ever heard

Comment: Why would this be CPU intensive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that, rather than using events, you use a concurrent queue data structure and a multiple producer, single consumer model.  Think of the tag reader threads as producers, and the processing thread as consumers.

When a thread receives a tag from a reader, it adds that tag to the queue, not worrying about duplicates or anything.  Heck, you might *want* that duplicate information at some point.  No reason to throw it out right here.

The consumer waits on the queue, taking items off and processing them one at a time.

The `BlockingCollection` class is perfect for this.

```
// Shared queue.  Assuming that a tag is simply a string.
BlockingCollection<string> TagQueue = new BlockingCollection<string>();

// Tag reader threads (producers)
while (!ShutdownMessageReceived)
{
    string tag = GetTagFromReader(); // however that's done
    TagQueue.Add(tag);
}

// Processing thread (consumer)
while (!ShutdownMessageReceived)
{
    string tag = TagQueue.Take();
    // process the tag
}
```

`BlockingCollection` supports multiple producers and consumers, so you can have as many of each as you like.  The `Take` method will block until an item is available.  It's a non-busy wait, so there's no polling overhead.

This kind of thing is very easy to implement with `BlockingCollection`, and makes for clean and simple code that performs very well.

Comment: Concurrent Dictionary might be useful too

Comment: The reason for ignoring the duplicates was that these 2 readers are working together as a single doorway. i.e. at 14:02:39 (hh:mm:ss) there was tags x & y in range of this doorway.

Comment: I've never had to write a threading app outside of a uni project, so whilst familar with consumer producer princible, I have a concern. If the readers are adding tags to the BlockingCollection as a producer, is there not a risk the Translation of tags (Consumers) falls behind. Whilst sure this model could handle 100's tags per second, if there is no consumer then the producer could be adding tags to a collection that could be read at a later time when the tag is not actually in the doorway anymore, although im sure the answer to this is to turn the producer off.

Comment: For reference tags are read from the reader (using an SDK provided by the manufacturer), by subscribing to a TagsReadReportEvent, which contains an event argument with an IList (bad practice) collection of strings which are the tags IDs.

Comment: @JonWillis: I would have the consumer do the duplicate removal. That simplifies the producers and puts the duplicate removal in a single place.  And, yes, if tags come in too fast then the consumer could fall behind, but in practice it will only fall behind when there is a heavy load (lots of tags coming in very quickly). At that point, the queue holds the backlog.  But again, there should be only a brief delay, if any. If it's a problem, then add another consumer. And, yes, it makes little sense to be running the producers if there's no consumer.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, So would this be a better idea. Ignoring the GUI for now. The main program thread could create a ReaderControl class. This class would load in the configuration for each reader and start them on there own thread (not sure how to do that yet), which add each tag ID into a BlockingCollection. The main thread would then also fire up some Translator objects which each run on there own thread, read a tag from the BlockingCollection. From this point the Translator could either fire an event as in my initial answer or add the translated tag to a new BlockingCollection for later use?

Comment: @JonWillis: Yes, that's the idea. I would start with a single Translator, as I suspect that it will be able to handle the load quite easily. You'll probably want the Translator to put the translated tags into a second `BlockingCollection` or some other collection that is read periodically (on a timer) to update the GUI.

Comment: @ Jim Mischel, Cheers I'll give it a go. Out of interest is there a rule of thumb when threads should be used, because I would have gone with the event-driven approach I originally suggested. I still do not see the advantage the threading has over the event driven approach.
Are you aware of any good samples/tutorials on using threading in a fashion above for C#, i.e. the ReaderControl puts each RFID reader in its own thread, and that thread will sit and listen to events. From what I know when you start a thread, i.e. DoWork() you are running just 1 method on a class, not processing its events.

Comment: @Jim Mischel, I've written a proof of concept sample app and it seems to work. I have started 3 fake readers which fire events that tags are seen like the real hardware, these are handled and the tag data added to a BlockingCollection. In the meantime I have 1 or more TagTranslators reading the collection and adding data to a translated collection. Next task is just to keep the tag data display on screen for a finate amount of time from when the tag was read, so the screen will display peoples names of those who have been caught in the RFID readers field.

Comment: @JonWillis: I'm glad it's working out for you. As far as a "rule of thumb," I'd have to give that some thought. It looked like a producer/consumer problem to me, and that to me usually means a queue and separate threads. I tend to leave the event mechanism for GUI stuff and other low-bandwidth tasks. I'm not saying that my way is best--just that it seems to have worked well for me.

Comment: @ Jim Mischel, There is little information on events vs. threads. I think the difference maybe a thread is for processing something that may take a significant time, in the sample i wrote I use Sleep(Random.Next(50,600)) for the translation method. In my demo program there is no task will take along time to accomplish as the tag translation is an in-memory collection rather than an embedded database as the number of unique tags is low. My new approach maybe readers and translators using threads in the ReaderControl Class. And the ReaderControl expose the real objects tags relate to.